# Why is soft body modifier always on top of modifier stack?

Tags: modifiers, soft-body

[image]

It doesn't matter when I add soft body modifier, it is always the first modifier, and can't be moved down. Why is this?

Comment: I don't think any modifiers aside from [deform](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/modeling/modifiers/index.html#deform) modifiers can be above soft body in the modifier stack. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to use SimpleDeform modifier to bend a sheet,then simulate the sheet falling onto bed.

Comment: I dont want to move it down,I want to add it to the botttom,like cloth modifier,but every time it just go straight to top

Answer (score 2):

If you can read the error message at the top it says, "Can't move beyond a non-deforming modifier". It basically means deformation modifiers are always on the top.